# Select sum from 2 different table in one Linq with one query

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have two tables

```
Incomes:
[Id]
[AmountOfMoneyEarnt]
[Date]
[AccountId]
```

and

```
Spendings
[Id]
[AmountOfMoneySpent]
[Date]
[AccountId]
```

I would like to create a LINQ query in C# to get the Sum of total Incomes and sum of total spendings, but I'd like to be queried in one roundtrip. Obviously I want to know the account balance, TotalIncome-TotalSpendings with one SQL server roundtrip. Is that possible somehow?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you started, then it will will be helpful add code also.

Comment: I tried this:
                from incomes in
                    _incomeRepository.Select(x => new { add = x.AmountOfMoneyEarnt, accountId = x.AccountId })
                from spendings in
                    _spendingsRepository.Select(x => new { add = x.AmountOfMoneySpent, accountId = x.AccountId })
                
                select incomes.add - spendings.add;

Comment: The AccountId is the relation

Comment: in your table there will more than one entry for a particular accountID . am i correct.?

Comment: @VajdaEndre: edit your question instead of commenting it

Comment: You want this information by `AccountId`. Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do that in one roundtrip, you can use LINQ [Concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351755(v=vs.110).aspx) operator which is the equivalent of the SQL `UNION ALL` on a common anonymous type projection including account Id and the amount (positive for incomes and negative for spendings), group the result by account and calculate the balance like this

```
var query = 
    db.Incomes.Select(i => new { AccountId = i.AccountId, Amount = i.AmountOfMoneyEarnt })
    .Concat(
    db.Spendings.Select(s => new { AccountId = s.AccountId, Amount = -s.AmountOfMoneySpent })
    )
    .GroupBy(e => e.AccountId)
    .Select(g => new { AccountId = g.Key, Balance = g.Sum(e => e.Amount) });
```

If you need just the balance for a specific account, then it could be like this

```
var accountId = ...;
var accountBalance = 
    db.Incomes.Where(i => i.AccountId == accountId).Select(i => i.AmountOfMoneyEarnt)
    .Concat(
    db.Spendings.Where(s => s.AccountId == accountId).Select(s => -s.AmountOfMoneySpent)
    )
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
    .Sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

If the tables aren't related at all and you want to select a sclar value:

```
var totalIncomesAndSpendings = new { 
    TotalIncomes = db.Incomes.Sum(x => x.AmountOfMoneyEarnt),
    TotalSpendings = db.Spendings.Sum(x => x.AmountOfMoneySpent)
};

var result = new { 
    TotalIncomes = totalIncomesAndSpendings.TotalIncomes,
    TotalSpendings = totalIncomesAndSpendings.TotalSpendings,
    AccountBalance = totalIncomesAndSpendings.TotalIncomes - totalIncomesAndSpendings.TotalSpendings
};
```

> I'd like to be queried in one transaction

You can wrap it in a [`TransactionScope`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
{
   // ...
}
```

Comment: The TransactionScope will solve that query will be returned with one SQL server round trip?

Comment: @VajdaEndre: you are confusing things. A transaction does not mean that you have one roundtrip. You should really
make more of an effort to explain your requirement. If you want one roundtrip write a stored-procedure.